# How to get the token value from response body?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I tried to get the token value from response.body and store in shared preferences.

Here is the JSON response I got:

```
{"meta":{"error":false,"message":"","statusCode":200},"response":{"token":"JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0Z62Q_NQJcK0dFCKiUOsl-k","user":{"id":12,"name":"suuu","firstName":"sss","lastName":"ss","icNumber":null,"email":"wew@example.com","description":"Retails Test","gender":"Male","phoneNumber":"0123456789","website":"retailsexample.com","createdAt":"2017-09-15 11:27:42","updatedAt":"2019-08-21 16:08:32","oldEmailData":null,"profilePictures":[{"width":795,"height":800
```

I tried to print the token like this but it shows null result:

```
  print('access token is -> ${json.decode(response.body)[ 'token']}');
```

So I have this code to get and store token:

```
  if(request.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  if(jsonResponse != null) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token']);
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }
```

So, how do I get the token from response.body?

Answer (score 0):

Following line will get the token into a string variable :

```
String token = jsonResponse['response']['token']
```

In your code, just replace

```
sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token'])
```

with

```
sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['response']['token'])
```